# Set the Compton .config file

Tags: linux

I have the following command to set various visual settings such as opacity.

```
compton -r 12 -o 0.75 -l -15 -t -15 -I 0.028 -O 0.03 -D 3 -c -f -C -F -G
```

I need these configurations to be written in a .conf file, but it doesn't work for some reason and I don't know how to do it correctly. What is the equivalent of this line in a configuration file? Thanks!

Comment: Usually config files follow a format such as ini, env, yaml etc., which is usually mentioned in man or info pages